# Проблемка с собственным ProgressBar vba

Tags: vba, progress-bar

В Module1 есть процедура перебора значений рабочего листа книги с подсчетом процента заполненности. Код работает, но далее появились файлы с количеством записей более 12000 и во время выполнения процедуры заметно подвисает обновление userform. И чтобы пользователь не волновался решил завести свой индикатор хода процесса. Работает в итоге как пулемет)) - использованная форма для вывода процента хода выполнения зацикливается на бесконечность и выглядит, как пулемет на экране.
Как исправить ситуацию ,чтобы форма визуализации хода процесса все таки выгружалась из памяти. Процедура, где этот код Module1/ CheckDataFromFile().

Ссылка на исходник приложения и файла с данными из которого они подгружаются в приложение и обратно копируются, когда с ними поработают. https://yadi.sk/d/y392lQY-3ivgTw

Comment: язык какой?Поставьте пожалуйста тэг .

Comment: Перед началом определите количество обрабатываемых строк. И отображайте процент обработанных, а не количество.

Comment: Количество итераций в начале я определяю из количества строк и передаю в переменной. Но работать оно начинает правильно. Исключением является то, что после 100% UserForm используемая под ProgresBar запускается снова и снова и так бесконечно. Мне кажется, что эта форма запущенная из Module1 с параметром 0 (Modal) не может быть выгружена из памяти после окончания цикла, поскольку доступ к модальному окну блокируется.

Comment: Запускаю пошаговый используя точку остановки. Все работает, как и должно. Форма модальная скрывается и видна только основная форма с результатом. Но, если не ставить точку остановки, то все крутится бесконечно.

Comment: Akina, спасибо. Разобрался. Много возвратов к процедуре цикла из разных событий, поэтому и зацикливало.